# Generate Presigned Url for Azure Blob throws Null pointer exception

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-sas

I want to generate a Presigned URL /SAS so that anyone with that url can access my file.

SDK Version : 12.8.0

I wrote the foll code :

```
BlockBlobClient blockBlobClient = objectStoreService.getBlobContainerClient().getBlobClient(fileName).getBlockBlobClient();

        String blobUrl = Utility.urlDecode(blockBlobClient.getBlobUrl());
        BlobSasPermission blobPermission = new BlobSasPermission()
                .setReadPermission(true);

        BlobServiceSasSignatureValues blobServiceSasSignatureValues = new BlobServiceSasSignatureValues(
                OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).plusSeconds(1000 * 60 * 60),
                blobPermission
        );
  
        blobUrl = blobUrl + "?" + blockBlobClient.generateSas(blobServiceSasSignatureValues);
```

But the code throws error as

> java.lang.NullPointerException: The argument must not be null or an empty string. Argument name: storageSharedKeyCredentials.

Edit 1 : Tried with :

```
UserDelegationKey userDelegationKey = blobServiceClient.getUserDelegationKey(keyStart,keyExpiry);

String blobUrl = Utility.urlDecode(blobClient.getBlobUrl());

blobUrl = blobUrl + "?" + blobClient.generateUserDelegationSas(blobServiceSasSignatureValues,userDelegationKey);
```

But now getting :

"Status code 403, "`AuthenticationFailed`Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.\nRequestId:7b0f0d75-d01e-00a8-4d84-7c9aa3000000\nTime:2021-07-19T09:54:31.1312999ZThe specified signed resource is not allowed for the this resource level"",

Comment: Error is pretty straightforward - You will need to create `storageSharedKeyCredentials` to sign your SAS.

Comment: @GauravMantri , I dont have the account key to create the credentials. In my organization, we get access to blob store via service which only provides a sasToken, container name and container uri

Comment: To generate a SAS token you will need either the account key or use Azure AD access token. You cannot generate a SAS token using another SAS token.

Comment: Oh ok. @GauravMantri, is there any other way wherein I can generate a presigned url for my file using these credentials ( Sas Token, Account name, Container URI, Container Name) ?

Comment: Sure you can. I thought you wanted to create a new SAS token. Do you want to create a SAS URL for a blob given all these parameters. Correct?

Comment: Also, please edit your question and include the SDK version you're using.

Comment: @GauravMantri Yes....Have edited and added the version .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a SAS token with valid permissions, blob container URL and the name of the blob, you can generate the SAS URL for the blob using this simple logic:

`{blob-container-url}/{blob-name}?{sas-token}`

If you want to use the SDK, first you will create a `BlobContainerClient` using your blob container URL and SAS token and then create a `BlockBlobClient` using that blob container client:

```
BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClientBuilder()
    .endpoint("{blob-container-url}?{sas-token}")
    .buildClient();

BlockBlobClient blockBlobClient = blobContainerClient.getBlobClient("{blob-name}").getBlockBlobClient();
```

You can then use this `blockBlobClient` to perform operations on your blob. You can use [`getUrl()`](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/java/azure-storage-blob/12.12.0/index.html) method to get the URL of the blob.

Comment: Hi, where is the url getting generated in this code? I want to share the url with client so that they can access/download the file directly..

Comment: You can use [`getUrl()`](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/java/azure-storage-blob/12.12.0/index.html) method to get the URL of the blob.

Comment: This is not a sharable URL right? Client wont be able to access the resource out of this url.

Comment: This will be a shareable URL. Please give it a try.

Comment: Have tried it... get error as public access not allowed to this storage account

Comment: This is a storage account configuration issue. Please contact your Azure administrators to allow SAS token based access to your storage resources.